# How to find and highlight next instance of word in richtextbox in visual basic?

Tags: vba

Here is the visual basic windows application form I am currently working on.

https://i.snag.gy/EzoXr3.jpg

How can I write code for the find next button like in this video.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u93h9jn605uhwsu/CPT341Project2Walkthrough.avi?dl=0

If I can get a syntax to store a index variable outside the private sub of findnext button,  I can solve the problem. Because everytime I click the findnext button, I have to find the respective instance of that word in the filetext. Or I can apply some code to find it in the substring of remaining text after its first occurrence.

Below is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
'Enter your name
'Date
'Class - CPT 341 VB.NET NJIT

Private Sub openBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles openBtn.Click
    If OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        fileText.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog.FileName)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    'Bring the form to the inital state for a different search
    Dim temp As String = fileText.Text
    fileText.Text = temp
    outputIndex.ForeColor = Color.Black

    'MessageBox to show error for empty search textbox
    If inputText.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Text to Search", "CPT 341 Fall 2018 - Project 2")
    Else
        'Declare variables
        Dim txt As String : Dim x As Integer = 0 : Dim output As String
        txt = inputText.Text
        If fileText.Text.IndexOf(txt) <> -1 Then
            Dim idx As Integer = CStr(fileText.Text.IndexOf(txt))
            outputIndex.Text = idx

            'Find and highlight the first word searched in the RichTextBox
            fileText.Find(txt, x, fileText.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
            fileText.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow

            'populate the string with ANSI numbers
            output = Asc(txt(0))
            For x = 1 To (txt.Length - 1)
                output = output & " " & Asc(txt(x))
            Next x
            outputANSI.Text = output

        ElseIf fileText.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please open a file to search from", "CPT 341 Fall 2018 - Project 2")

        Else
            outputIndex.Text = txt & " is not found"
            'Bring the form to inital state
            fileText.Text = temp
            'Change the index textbox text color to red
            outputIndex.ForeColor = Color.Red
            'Empty the ANSI textbox
            outputANSI.Text = ""
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub btnFind_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFind.Click

    Dim txt As String = inputText.Text
    Dim Index As Integer = fileText.Text.IndexOf(txt) + txt.Length
    'Find and highlight the word searched in the RichTextBox other than first occurrence

    fileText.Find(txt, Index, fileText.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None)
    fileText.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow
    Index = fileText.Text.IndexOf(txt, Index) + txt.Length + 1

End Sub

Private Sub btnWords_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWords.Click
    wordCount.Text = fileText.Text.Split(" ").Length
End Sub

Private Sub btnChars_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnChars.Click
    charCount.Text = fileText.Text.Length
End Sub
End Class
```

Or any other suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: btnFind_Click  is the part I need code for. Thanks :)

Comment: I just found the solution. Can you delete the question.